# Remote Powershell in Exchange 2007

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2007, powershell

Im wondering if it's posible to use Powershell from a remote computer (without installing Exchange manegment tools on the remote computer) to create or list user mailboxes. And if so, how?

Comment: This might be what you looking for http://www.powershellserver.com/manage-exchange-server-remotely-with-powershell-server/

Answer (score 3):

To be able to run Exchange powershell commands you need to load the Exchange Snap in into powershell, and I do not believe there is a way to get this without installing the management tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you go with Exchange 2007 SP2, you will have support for PowerShell v2.  With PowerShell v2 on the client and server, you should be able to do exactly what is described [HERE](http://blogs.msexchange.org/walther/2009/04/22/connecting-to-a-remote-exchange-2010-organization-using-remote-powershell/) (even if that link is for Ex2010).